# Only open files of a certain type in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code, is it possible to open a project directory, but only have it load certain types of files? Say, for example, you wanted to open up a directory that consisted of folders containing JavaScript files and images, but you only wanted the JavaScript files loaded in Visual Studio Code, is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

The `files.exclude` setting within the Settings editor can allow you to configure glob patterns to exclude files and folders.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Text Editor > Files > Exclude`

And then add a pattern for excluding the type of files you don't want to see. For the example of images you might add a couple like this:

```
**/*.png
**/*.jpg
```

This is just a more specific version of the answer from @Angelica - all credit to her!